# Construct array from flattened string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, data-conversion

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/3WdzL/1/

I need to convert locale JS object files to flattened versions and back again:

**Orig locale object:**

```
var localeObj = {
    toolbar: {
        link: {
            back: 'Back',
            menu: 'Menu',
        },
        flatTest: 'something'
    },
    countries: [
        ["AF", "Afghanistan"],
        ["AX", "Åland Islands"],
        ['nested', [1, 2, 3, 4]],
        ["AL", "Albania"]
    ]
};
```

**Using the following function:**

```
function flattenObj(obj) {
    var flattenedObj = {};

    var walk = function(obj, stringMap) {

        for(k in obj) {
            var computedKey = stringMap + (stringMap ? '.' + k : k);

            if(typeof obj[k] !== 'object') {
                flattenedObj[computedKey] = obj[k];
            } else {
                walk(obj[k], computedKey);
            }
        }
    };

    walk(obj, '');
    return flattenedObj;
}
```

**Would produce a flattened object:**

```
{
    toolbar.link.back: Back
    toolbar.link.menu: Menu
    toolbar.flatTest: something
    countries.0.0: AF
    countries.0.1: Afghanistan
    countries.1.0: AX
    countries.1.1: Åland Islands
    countries.2.0: nested
    countries.2.1.0: 1
    countries.2.1.1: 2
    countries.2.1.2: 3
    countries.2.1.3: 4
    countries.3.0: AL
    countries.3.1: Albania 
}
```

**Converting back with the following func works fine for objects:**

```
function deepenObj(obj) {
  var deepenedObj = {}, tmp, parts, part;

  for (var k in obj) {
    tmp = deepenedObj;
    parts = k.split('.');

    var computedKey = parts.pop();

    while (parts.length) {
      part = parts.shift();
      tmp = tmp[part] = tmp[part] || {};
    }

    tmp[computedKey] = obj[k];
  }

  return deepenedObj;
}
```

**But produces a structure like this for the arrays:**

```
region: {
    country: {
        0: {
            0: 'AF',
            1: 'Afghanistan'
        },
        ...
        2: {
            0: 'nested',
            1: {
                0: 1,
                1: 2,
                3: 4,
                4: 5
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously this isn't the desired results for the arrays and I haven't been able to come up with a safe, elegant or even working solution yet. PS I am happy to save the arrays to strings differently if it makes converting back easier. Thanks!

Comment: You could test whether the key is numeric and then decide to create an array instead. This would not allow numeric keys in properties though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should either keep track if an object is actually an array:

```
var walk = function(obj, stringMap) {
    if (Array.isArray(obj) {
        for (var k = 0; k < obj.length; k++)
            var computedKey = stringMap ? stringMap + ',' + k : k;
    } else {
        for (var k in obj) {
            var computedKey = stringMap ? stringMap + '.' + k : k;
        ...
```

Then, when deepening:

```
for (var k in obj) {
    tmp = deepenedObj;
    parts = ["."].concat(k.split(/([\.,])/));

    var computedKey = parts.pop(), sign;

    while (parts.length) {
        sign = parts.shift();
        part = !parts.length ? computedKey : parts.shift();
        tmp = tmp[part] = tmp[part] || (sign === "," ? [] : {});
    }

    tmp[computedKey] = obj[k];
}
```

Note that `Array.isArray` could be `undefined`. You can use `obj instanceof Array` instead.

This solution works if `localeObj` is an object literal and not an array, because the first point/comma isn't saved in the computed key. You can modify the function if you need to.

The trick here is to use an unusual behaviour of `split` that pushes captured groups in the splitted array when used with regular expressions, so before every key part there's the proper separator.

Comment: Very nice good idea, thanks for your time. The initial conversion looks ok (commas for arrays) but something is going wrong when converting it back into an array I'll try and find out why: http://jsfiddle.net/3EFuA/

Comment: @infensus Yeah, right, I didn't have the chance to test my answer :) Modified accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()`:

```
var flattenedObj = JSON.stringify(localeObj);

vat deepenedObj = JSON.parse(flattenedObj);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wqvDx/)

Comment: The problem with this is that I need:
`'toolbar.link.back'`
not `"toolbar": {"link": "back"}`